# Toolbar not overlapping with tablayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement collapsing toolbar

When the toolbar is collapsed, I want the toolbar to overlap the tab layout, it should be on top of that. How do I implement it

My code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/images"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/index"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/index"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="TEXT"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
               >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="hello"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When expanded Tab layout is overlapping view pager, when collapsed,
three layer overlapping each other , View pager, tab layout, toolbar

How do I implement it?

Comment: You want the toolbar to scroll up? Didn't really understand your question

Comment: @silverFoxA actually I wanted the tablayout to be on top of toolbar when collapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want to collapse tablayout also:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/images"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/index"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                       android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                       android:layout_gravity="top"
                       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                       android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
                       app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
           >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="hello"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Actually I dont want it to collapse, I want tab layout to be under toolbar